# How do you interpret an assert statement if it contains an 'if .... else ....'?

Tags: python, testing, assert

EDIT: its answered, I did not understand what a ternary operator is.
For people from the future that have the similar question: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html

I'm studying 'assert' statements in python and I don't understand the following sentence.

`assert .. if ... else ... and ...`

So if I understand correctly you have to use the above if you want to test an 'if else ' statement. You have to insert it right after the "if" statement the following: assert (P1 if E else P2) and E

For example

```
assert (y == builtins.max(x, y) if x < y else x == builtins.max(x, y)) and x < y
```

If understand `assert y == builtins.max(x,y)`
It just checks if the condition is true or not and when it is not true it returns an assertion error. However in the case of :
`assert (y == builtins.max(x, y) if x < y else x == builtins.max(x, y)) and x < y`

I have no clue what is happening. It apparently always returns true as well. But I cannot even guess what is exactly happening. I looked up what an assert statement does and the only thing it does is: `assert <condition>,<error message>` so check the condition and possibly return an error message. However I don't understand how `... if ... else ... and ...` is a condition. I understand the `and` but how exactly do you interpret the `if else` part in that condition?

I don't really understand what I'm not understanding. It's probably very trivial. Hopefully someone can help me. Sorry for my spelling mistakes.

EDIT: its answered, I did not understand what a ternary operator is.
For people from the future that have the similar question: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on here is the assertion of a ternary.

This:

```py
(y == builtins.max(x, y) if x < y else x == builtins.max(x, y)) and x < y
```

is conceptually:

```py
A if cond else B # and cond2, but we'll come to that
```

Which evaluates first to A or B.  We then assert that, so

```py
assert A if cond else B
```

is the same as

```
x = A if cond else B
assert x
```

This *particular* ternary is not straightforward.  It's equivalent to this:

```py
if x < y:
    res = y == builtins.max(x, y)
else:
    res  = x == builtins.max(x,y)

assert res and x < y
```

IMHO it's rather unclear.  It's funny anyhow, as in most contexts you can just do `max()` rather than `builtins.max()`.  Perhaps it belongs in a test, or a context where `max()` has (unwisely) been overidden? [Thinking it through this is probably a test for `builtins.max` isn't it?]

### References

For more information on python's ternary construction see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).

Comment: Thank you ... I did not understand what a ternary operator is. I now understand what the statement is.

Comment: @bananenheld feel free to accept if this answer is :)  Where did you find this assert btw?